# Progress bar with progress text changing during specified time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have trouble programming progress bar with progress text. Consider such a situation.

I have bar called `#bar` with specified `height`. It should rise proportionally from 0 to 100% during changing its internal value called `percent`. It raises via css transition in specified interval of time (i.e. 1 second). So I change height from 0 to 100px in one second. I also want to change the value describing progress so it writes on the bar 50 if it has 50% of progress done and so on.

I started doing it via `setTimeout` or `setInterval` and each iteration increments also height of progress bar and updates progress text (like 1, 2, 3 ... 100). Unfortunately, if I set interval time to 1ms, the progress bar finishes progressing with 100px after time longer than 100ms. That's why I've chosen transition because it will last for a certain ammount of time. The problem is I do not have any idea how to change progress text value during animation to appropriate values. Do you have any advice?

Comment: This could nicely be illustrated if you created a fiddle of your problem. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/). Makes it easier to solve your specific problem.

Comment: How do you know the progress of whatever you're doing? Is this via an ajax request?

Comment: I think they are using css transition timings, and will match the same timing with the jQuery.